# Operator '>=' is not defined for type 'Integer' and 'closedxml.excel.ixlrow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, closedxml

I tried to add pagebreak every 13 row with ClosedXML but i got stuck to solve this

```
Dim xrow As Integer = 0
Do Until xrow >= ws.LastRowUsed()
   ws.PageSetup.AddHorizontalPageBreak(xrow)
   xrow += 13
Loop
```

am getting the error as

> Operator '>=' is not defined for type 'Integer' and
>   'closedxml.excel.ixlrow

Comment: `ws.LastRowUsed()` may not be a integer value that's why you are getting such error

Comment: thanks i added `ws.LastRowUsed().RowNumber()` then it work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

> Do Until xrow >= ws.LastRowUsed()
>   ws.LastRowUsed() '<-- will point to the row not the row number hence it cannot be compared with an integer value that's why you are getting such error message while running the code.
>   So make change it as :

```
ws.LastRowUsed().RowNumber() '<-- will give you the specific row number
```

Hence your code will be like:

```
Dim xrow As Integer = 0
Do Until xrow >= ws.LastRowUsed().RowNumber()
   ws.PageSetup.AddHorizontalPageBreak(xrow)
   xrow += 13
Loop
```